# If $A$ is a square matrix of order 3 such that $|A|=2$, then find the value of $|(\operatorname{adj}A^{-1})^{-1}|$

Tags: matrices

$A^{-1}=\dfrac{\operatorname{adj}(A)}{|A|}$, $\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})=\dfrac 12 \operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(A))$, $|\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})|=\dfrac 12 |A|^2$, $|\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})^{-1})|=\dfrac 12$.

But the given answer is $4$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think it's better to use $\text({adj}(A^{-1}))^{-1}$=$\text{adj}(A)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second step is already wrong. If $A$ is $n\times n$, $\operatorname{adj}(kA)$ is equal to $k^{n-1}\operatorname{adj}(A)$ rather than $k\operatorname{adj}(A)$. Therefore $\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})=\operatorname{adj}\left(\frac12\operatorname{adj}(A)\right)$ should be equal to $\frac14\operatorname{adj}(A)$.

The correct answer should be
$$
\left|\left(\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})\right)^{-1}\right|
=|\operatorname{adj}(A)|
=|A|^{3-1}=2^2=4,
$$
where we have used the identities that $\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})= (\operatorname{adj} A)^{-1}$ and that $|\operatorname{adj}(A)|=|A|^{n-1}$.

Comment: Can I get a proof for $adj (A^{-1})=(adj A)^{-1}$? I was not aware of that property, which would have made this a lot simpler

Comment: @Aditya This is a special case (with $B=A^{-1}$) of the identity that $adj(AB)=adj(B)adj(A)$. The more cleaner proofs of this identity involve the concept of *indeterminate*, which is typically taught in an abstract algebra course. More specifically, let the entries of $A$ and $B$ be $2n^2$ indeterminantes. Then $A$ and $B$ are invertible. Therefore $adj(BA)=\det(BA)(BA)^{-1}=(\det(A)A^{-1})(\det(B)B^{-1})=adj(A)adj(B)$.

Comment: So what should be the general procedure in case of $adj A^{-1}$, if $|A|$ is known

Comment: @Aditya After the identity is proved for matrices with indeterminates, the matrix can be "specialised" to numeric matrices (by "substituting" numerical values into the indeterminates) and hence the identity still holds for numeric matrices, although $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily invertible.

Comment: Over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, one may also invoke a "continuity argument": since invertible matrices are dense in the matrix space and the adjugate of a matrix is a continuous function of the matrix's entries, it suffices to prove the identity for invertible $A$ and $B$ only. That is, if $\{A_n\}$ and $\{B_n\}$ are two sequences of invertible matrices that converge to $A$ and $B$, then $adj(BA)=\lim_{n\to\infty}adj(B_nA_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}adj(A_n)adj(B_n)=adj(A)adj(B)$.

Answer (score 2):

Using your first equation, we have that 
$$A = \frac{\text{adj}(A^{-1})}{|A^{-1}|}$$
Rearranging, we have 
$$||A^{-1}|\cdot A| = |A^{-1}|^3 \cdot |A| = |\text{adj}(A^{-1})| = |A^{-1}|^2$$
Note that in the second equality, we raise $|A^{-1}|$ to the third power because we are dealing with square matrices of order 3. (The proof you gave goes wrong because you have not taken into account the order of the matrices.) We know that determinants are inverted by taking the inverse, so we have that
$$|\text{adj}(A^{-1})^{-1}| = \left(|A^{-1}|^2\right)^{-1} = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{-1} = 4$$